# Ioc container for Web Api 2.2

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container, autofac, asp.net-web-api2

I'm looking into using a IOC container for Web Api 2.2 (recently released). I want to use it as a dependency resolver for Web API controllers along with injecting my own dependencies.

I've tried using Unity and Autofac, using there Web Api nuget packages, without success. I've come to conclusion that they doesn't support Web Api 2.2 (yet).

Is there any other known IOC container that support Web Api 2.2?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that they don't support it? All major frameworks (Autofac, Simple Injector, Ninject, Castle Windsor, StructureMap, Unity) have support for Web API.

Comment: I tried using Unity and Autofac, both targets System.Web.Http library version 5.1.0. Web Api 2.2 uses System.Web.Http version 5.2.0. Got exceptions trying to invoke the web api controllers using the above ioc´s.

Comment: That's what bindingRedirects are for. If you add those libraries to your project using NuGet, in most cases NuGet will change your config file to change the binding redirects. If this doesn't happen, you can do it easily by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added assembly redirects to System.Web.Http 5.2.0.0 and got rid of the exceptions. Also noted that I hadn't registered all types (dependencies of the controller) and therefore the controller wasn't instantiated.

Thanks, works fine now. Is it possible to get Unity to throw exception if it fails to instantiate due to lacking dependencies instead of being silent?

Comment: The answer contains a question, and deserves a new Stackoverflow question on its own. But as far as I know, there is no easy way in Unity to verify the complete configuration, and when it comes to detecting other kinds of configuration errors such as [Captive Dependencies](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/), you're left completely in the dark.